# Accessing external json file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've an external cars.json file which has json objects.

```
{
  "Holden": [
    {
      "door": 2,
      "color": "Black",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Black Holden 2 Doors"
    },
    {
      "door": 4,
      "color": "Green",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Green  Holden 4 Doors"
    },
    {
      "door": 6,
      "color": "Blue",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Blue  Holden 6 Doors"
    }
  ],
  "VW": [
    {
      "door": 2,
      "color": "Red",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Red VW 2  Doors"
    },
    {
      "door": 4,
      "color": "Pink",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Pink VW 4 Doors"
    },
    {
      "door": 6,
      "color": "Grey",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Grey VW 6  Doors"
    }
  ],
  "Toyota": [
    {
      "door": 2,
      "color": "Black",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Black  Toyota 2 Doors"
    },
    {
      "door": 4,
      "color": "White",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=White Toyota 4 Doors"
    },
    {
      "door": 6,
      "color": "Pink",
      "img-url": "https://placehold.it/400x400/ccc/666?text=Pink  Toyota 6 Doors"
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically I'm trying to display Holden, VW and Toyota on page load and then when you click on say "Holden" it displays the number of doors that car is available and once you select the doors it displays the "color" that car is available in and finally an image of that car.

My question is, how do I access the jSON object from the external file using .getJSON method?

This is what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON( "cars.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

But the above doesn't output anything.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "external file"?  Where is the file stored?  How do you expect to access the file?

Comment: @Wyck It's a local file as you can see in the code I put in its been referenced in $.getJSON() object.

Comment: You should not be able to access the external file using it. Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON). You can use npm lib like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-json-file) to get the job done

Comment: Local to what?  You're in a browser, right?  So what do you mean by "local file"?  Do you mean a file stored in the filesystem of the user's computer?  Are you expecting to fetch it with a `file://` url?  Or is this a file that was selected by the user with an `<input type="file">`  Or do you have a HTTP server that will serve up that file for you and it just happens to be stored in same file system as the server?

Answer (score 1):

The File name is `a.json` 
Try using:

```
$.getJSON( "a.json", function( data ) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
$.getJSON( "example_file.json", function( data ) {
  Object.keys(data).map(function (item) {
      console.log(item) ---------> This will display Holden, VW and Toyota
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access local files from your web browser. You need to run a web server to access a file. This file should then be hosted on that web server. Locally you would then access this file over the URL http://localhost:8080 where the port depends on your web server.

You could e.g. run an Apache or a Node.js (express) web server.

This is due to security concerns: You do not want a web site to access your locally stored files. Therefore, this is not possible without serving it on a web server.

The path to the file would then be relative to the configured directory web server root. If, for example, the web server points to `C:\Users\user1\webserver` and you put your JSON file and your website in there, you could access the JSON file in JavaScript with the path `http://localhost:8080/cars.json` or with a relative path `/cars.json`.